# External TV Tuner+STB gives a black and white display with S-Video

Tags: s-video, rca

I have a PC monitor. I watched TV on this using an external TV tuner box just like this

[image: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/57629104/INTEX%20SkyView%20LCD%20%20TFT%20TV%20Tuner%20Box.JPG]

having ports : [image: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/57629104/M501-1334-out4-hl.jpg]
and it worked fine.

Now we have digitization compulsory in our area. So I have brought a SET top box to be attached to it.
The SetTop Box has 4 ports 
1. One Antenna In - Connected to the cable connection from the cable operator
2. One Video Out (Composite)
3. Two Audio (L+R)

Now I have an AV cable which I have connected to the back of set top box in the audio video ports.

On the other side of the cable I have hooked both the audio cables together using the connector like this

[image]

and on the remaining yellow video cable I have attached a connector like this

[image]

(rca to s-video) since the TV tuner only had the option for S-Video in.
Moreover the cable shipped with the TV tuner box.

I am getting both audio and video. but the issue is that the video is BLACK AND WHITE.
There is no problem with the signal that I receive from the operator as I tried with RF modulator and it worked. The only thing is very poor picture quality.

Also the TV tuner box can detect NTSC/PAL. I have also checked that. No issues with that.

Am I doing anything wrong?? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

S-video uses four wires to carry two signals:

- chrominace (the color signal)
- luminance (the grey-scale signal)

The B/W picture you do see implies that the chrominace (color) connection is broken.

Check the S-video connections and cable.  Try another S-video cable.

Comment: OK. I'll try replacing the s-video section..